# How does persisting the model increase accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score

whitewine_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', 
delimiter=';')

variables = ['alcohol_cat', 'alcohol', 'sulphates', 'density', 
'total sulfur dioxide', 'citric acid', 'volatile acidity', 
'chlorides']

X = whitewine_data[variables]
y = whitewine_data['quality']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

predictions = model.predict([[0.27, 0.36, 0.045, 170, 1.001, 
0.45, 8.9, 0]])
print(f'Predicted Output: {predictions}')
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy * 100}%')
print(f'F1 Score: {f1 * 100}% ')
```

This initial model resulted in a accuracy score of 57%

==============================================================

```
whitewine_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', 
delimiter=';')

# Variables to be dropped from the data set - NOT THE INPUT 
VARIABLES
variables = ['fixed acidity', 'residual sugar', 'free sulfur 
dioxide', 'pH', 'quality', 'isSweet']

X = whitewine_data.drop(variables, axis=1)
y = whitewine_data['quality']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.2)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

joblib.dump(model, 'WhiteWine_Quality_Predictor.joblib')
```

Creating the Saved model

==============================================================

```
whitewine_data = pd.read_csv('winequality-white.csv', 
delimiter=';') 

variables = ['volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'chlorides', 
'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'sulphates', 'alcohol', 
'alcohol_cat']

X_test = whitewine_data[variables]
y_test = whitewine_data['quality']  

model = joblib.load('WhiteWine_Quality_Predictor.joblib')

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
predictions = model.predict([[0.27, 0.36, 0.045, 170, 1.001, 
0.45, 10.9, 3]])

print(f'F1 Score: {f1 * 100}%')
print(f'Model Accuracy: {accuracy * 100}%')
print(f'Predicted Output: {predictions}')
```

Calling saved model now resulted in 92% accuracy

Question: How does calling a saved model result in the increase
of accuracy I saw

Comment: Please don't post images of your code. Copy/paste it into your question instead. No one wants to click on three seperate pictures to get an idea of what you are doing

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If the answer provided is what you were looking for, please consider to pin it as correct, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite a common mistake when handling with ML algorithms at the beginning.

In your second script, you are training the algorithm on the winequality-white.csv dataset, and then you are saving it. That's totally fine.

The problem is that in your third, you are using the algorithm on the exact same dataset you've used for training. You are basically predict observations that you used for training, so it's pretty obvious that the algorithm will predict them with 100% accuracy.

The approach of storing the algorithm is correct, but then you have to use another dataset for actually using it for predictions, not the same you used for training.

Comment: thanks for the reply, initially I was getting accuracy of 100% and in the third I changed what it is predicting and now getting 92%, would I have to change the test train split output to ensure i am not testing on trained data

Comment: you can split your initial dataset into 3 parts: 40 20 40. You can use the first 40 and 20 as train test, and then the last 40 as predictions after having saved the model